# Angular2 cli different component per page

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-directives, angular-cli

I have recently implemented angular2 cli on one of my site, because of angular2 upgrade.

I want to know how I can create different component per page without using route? Is it even possible?

right now its one big angular2 main bundle. kind of confused on how to decouple it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, I think is possible. You can use `ngIf`

I create a simple demo on [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/mAqh2MGumSzv4fLUYbCi?p=preview).

I hope it helps

Comment: No, I mean how to add different component at run time for different pages, without adding to main bundle js file

Answer (score 0):

@Kosmonaft  You did not use the routing mechanism, this is very simple switching.